# Failed to order the transaction. Error code: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE using raft consensus protocol

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, raft

I am facing this error while using Raft consensus protocol in which I have setup 5 orderers(1 in 1st server, 2 each in other 2 servers) namely orderer1 to orderer5.
Everything works fine with the setup and all the orderers are participating in the orderer election process but while I'm trying to invoke a transaction then I'm facing an error like this:

```
[ERROR] invoke-chaincode - Failed to order the transaction. Error code: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
```

This error comes only when i try to invoke using orderer2 but works well with any other orderer. Please help to resolve the issue.

Here are the logs of orderer2 and its running:

```
2019-08-13 07:05:59.374 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] run -> INFO 318 raft.node: 2 elected leader 4 at term 2 channel=invoice node=2
2019-08-13 07:05:59.375 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] serveRequest -> INFO 319 Raft leader changed: 0 -> 4 channel=invoice node=2
2019-08-13 07:05:59.580 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 31a Error reading from xx.xx.xx.xx:56890: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-08-13 07:05:59.580 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 31b streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=xx.xx.xx.xx:56890 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=207.535623ms
2019-08-13 07:13:20.952 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 320 [channel: invoice] Rejecting broadcast of normal message from xx.xx.xx.xx:56916 with SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE: rejected by Order: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 192.168.224.4:8050: connect: connection refused"
2019-08-13 07:13:20.952 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 321 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=xx.xx.xx.xx:56916 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=35.477429971s
```

Comment: cant you show docker logs and check if the orderer2 container is running or not?

Comment: I have added orderer logs in the question. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this very issue, orderer2 as well. It turns out for me, I had made a typo in the orderer config. In the General.Cluster section, I accidentally renamed the ClientCertificate and ClientPrivateKey fields to ServerCertificate and ServerPrivateKey. I switched them, left the Server* values blank and pointed to my client certs with the others and everything worked.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I have rechecked my certificates and all are fine and there is no problem with that. And, even I stopped my network and cleared everything and then restart the network then the same problem starts with orderer4 this time. So I don't think its some certificate issue.